# Resolving Unexpected token < in Chrome for Custom 403 Page

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, token, http-status-code-403

I saw some previous topics related to this but was unable to find a related solution.

On my WordPress blog, WeLearnChess.com, I created a custom 403 error page, and now I am getting a seemingly related syntax error in Chrome.  I enabled script debugging in the wp config file and checked with developer tools in Chrome, and I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < inaccessible:1
```

This appears to refer to my custom 403 page (http://www.welearnchess.com/inaccessible/). I have BulletProof Security Pro installed, so, to create the custom 403, I replaced the default 403 code with the following line of code via the BPS custom code field:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.welearnchess.com/inaccessible/
```

From various tutorials that I saw online, this seems like it should be correct, but I'm new to this so perhaps I've made a mistake that is causing the error. Another interesting point is that, after a hard browser refresh, sometimes the syntax error temporarily changes from :inaccessible to :index or maybe it was:index1 (I'm having trouble reproducing it now).

So, have I done something incorrect with my 403 custom code that could be causing the aforementioned error? Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide, and please let me know if I need to clarify the question further.

Comment: Maybe it is not JavaScript related, have a look at your PHP code (WordPress). Make sure the files you are including have no syntax errors and that they do not pre-maturely exit the PHP context that renders some javascript.. It may be a PHP error that gets rendered as JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I will check for php errors and report back. In the meantime, before I read these responses, I noticed that some of the errors on my site were related to YouTube embedding. I switched over to lazy loading them (via the WP YouTube Lyte plugin), and both the error in the OP and the js errors related to the YouTube embedding disappeared.  I'm wondering if this alone has resolved the issue.

Comment: and then the unexpected token error reappeared again later...also now appearing in edge but wasn't before. This error seems to appear intermittently--not sure what is triggering it, but perhaps the discussion below will clarify.

Comment: If you find comments -or answers useful, from anyone, remember to "up-vote" the comments and answers. If you do not show gratitude this way, people may become reluctant to comment or answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You plugin directory is throwing a 403 error, which means when including `<script>` tags with src like `http://www.welearnchess.com/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-social-deux/public/assets/js/min/us.script-min.js?ver=6.0.4` get redirected to your custom 403 page which is `http://www.welearnchess.com/inaccessible/`. There are a few instances of this for plugins: ultimate-social-deux, zf-wordpress-category-accordian, rain - where their assets that should be publicly accessible are 403ing. Which means, instead of the actual script your custom page is loaded in the script tag, which is as expected, is invalid JavaScript and hence the errors in your console.

Comment: This is interesting--I wonder if one of my security plugins is restricting access to the plugin files. Could this be related to the issue?

Comment: yes its highly likely that as part of the htaccess restrictions set by one of your security plugins, access to files in plugins directory is denied. 

would you mind creating a gist/pastebin of your current htaccess file?

Comment: Oh yeah, BPS Pro has quite a bit on lock down.  I didn't see this before, but the plugins htaccess file has a white list of plugins, and then has a forbidden section, that looks like this:

Comment: # FORBID REMOTE ACCESS TO THESE PLUGIN FILE TYPES FROM ANYONE EXCEPT YOU
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\.(7z|as|bat|bin|cgi|chm|chml|class|cmd|com|command|dat|db|db2|db3|dba|dll|DS_Store|exe|gz|hta|htaccess|htc|htm|html|html5|htx|idc|ini|ins|isp|jar|jav|java|js|jse|jsfl|json|jsp|jsx|lib|lnk|out|php|phps|php5|php4|php3|phtml|phpt|pl|py|pyd|pyc|pyo|rar|shtm|shtml|sql|swf|sys|tar|taz|tgz|tpl|txt|vb|vbe|vbs|war|ws|wsf|xhtml|z|zip)$ [NC]
# BEGIN PUBLIC IP
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^73.226.215.210$
# END PUBLIC IP
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

Comment: and here is the gist of the root htaccess file: https://gist.github.com/cheech1981/26fea55132bd9ecc207dc94d0edab09e#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: So I'm guessing I can add specific plugins that I want BPS Pro to trust to the whitelist but will wait for your feedback before I start playing around :)

Comment: okay that snippet in the comment shows that access to plugin file types of `js` is forbidden. You could simply allow all `js` files to be served, but yes a better option would be to whitelist individual plugins

Comment: Okay so I whitelisted the js files for my plugins. One of the plugin developers mentioned that I probably could have deactivated and reactivated BulletProof Security Pro, which I had thought of, but I didn't think to clear the cache--probably would have worked. Anyway I listed the files manually. In addition to fixing some issues with the plugins and increasing site speed, this appears, at least for now, to have addressed the issue in the OP. Hopefully it will last this time! :)  Thanks for your help--I really appreciate it.  Have a good one!